# Rails command line cannot do rails c anymore, only bundle exec rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, rake, chmod

I was being denied permission in my bin/rake and bin/rails so I executed chmod +x bin/rake and bin/rails. However when I do rails console or rails server I get

```
env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

the only work around is bundle exec rails console or bundle exec rails server. I was wondering why because in my other Rails projects and when I create new ones rails s/c still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your bin directory is corrupted, you need to regenerate it.
Please try the following command:

```
rm -r bin/*
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```